# Showing progress towards a two-step goal

Tags: interaction-design, visual-design, progress-bar, actions

I have a lightly interesting problem in that I need a system for awarding a t-shirt after two actions are taken. The two actions can happen anywhere within a 12 month span. It feels like overkill to implement some of the normal solutions bar or pie chart. I've done some simple sketches, but are there any commonly understood conventions for two-part goals?

[image: Example progress indicators]

Comment: If the actions are well defined, how about an ordered list with checkmarks on completed actions.

Comment: A good solution, but unfortunately it's fairly open. "Complete any two of these things and we'll give you a t-shirt"

Comment: +1 on the t-shirt, would need to see an example of it on-screen to ensure it is a good experience, but it relates to the offer at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Your half T-shirt indicator is good, still my suggestions are:

- **easy to recall** as time period between the actions could be quite large, users could forget about award when they visit the site next time, so provide description for this indicator, which is displayed as tooltip, etc.
- **non-pushing** award isn't primary functionality, so displaying "1 of 2" could look a bit obligatory for users
- **distinctive** design free T-shirt indicator to look like badge: nice-looking, noticeable, and not similair to your main products
- **CTA** use appropriate call to action in your indicator, like "Get your free T-shirt", or "Get free T-shirt for next item" , etc.
  [image]